# Pointer being invalidated?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, stdvector, nullptr

I'm having the problem of my pointers/objects being invalidated.

I have a class which is holding an std::vector< MyStruct* >.

They're being stored in a message handler function which accessess the std::vector directly.
Here's the function: (Socket::Server* is the thisptr which has been given to each receiving thread which is then being passed on into this function)

```
static void OnUpdateInGameState( Socket::Server* Server, int Client, const char* Data ) {
    Messages::MessageUpdateInGameState Message( Data );

    for ( auto GameState : Server->m_ClientGameState ) {
        if ( !GameState )
            continue;

        if ( GameState->Client == Client ) {
            GameState->Message.InGame = Message.message( ).InGame;
            snprintf( GameState->Message.Server, sizeof( Message.message( ).Server ), Message.message( ).Server );
            return;
        }
    }

    //No such object found, create it
    Server->m_ClientGameState.push_back( new InGameState_t( Client, Message.message( ) ) );
}
```

I've tried using smart pointers and other methods of allocation memory. All of them led to the pointer being valid for 1-5 calls and then being invalidated.

Why is that happening?

Comment: A [mcve] would be helpful.

Comment: Is posting GitHub links allowed? If so I could show the Socket Class I'm using as creating a MCVE would probably have to include all of that anyway.

Comment: In case of external corruption from another source, add a write to memory watch to the variable to understand when it goes "bad".